# For Google Chart, how to I determine the interval of a continuous h-axis with datetime format?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Currently I am using Google Chart (Column Chart) to show the target quantity every hour for latest 48 hours. My code is like below:

```
var oChartOptions = {   
    height:250,
    hAxis: {
      viewWindowMode:'explicit',
      viewWindow: {
        max: new Date()
        },
      format: "MM/dd h':00'",
      textStyle:{fontSize: 10},
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: 'red',"font-weight":"bold"
      },
      maxTextLines: 12
    }
  };

var nChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(nTarget);
var oChartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
oChartData.addColumn('datetime','Time');
oChartData.addColumn('number','Quantity');                 
oChartData.addRows(aData);    
nChart.draw(oChartData, oChartOptions);
```

Currently it works great, but for h-axis, it shows the label of time every 6 hours, and I want to shorten this interval from 6 to 2. After I tried a lot with the [document](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart), I still found no solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the tick interval with the last parameter (optional) of the `chxr` tag.
Here is an example :

```
chxr: 0,0,15,1
```

It will define a [0,15] interval on the first axis with a tick every one value.

Comment: what's 0,0,15,1?